# capturing (listening) globally to mouse and keyboard without consuming in X11

Tags: c++, c, linux, x11, xorg

I have this code which can listen globally to keyboard messages:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;


char keymap[32];
char prevKeymap[32];

bool hasTyped(Display* display)
{
    XQueryKeymap(display, keymap);
    for(int i=0; i<32; i++)
    {
        if (prevKeymap[i]!=keymap[i])
        {
            XQueryKeymap(display, prevKeymap);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main(int , char *[])
{
    //setBrightness(defaultBrightness);
    Display *display;
    Window root, fromroot, tmpwin;
    int x, y,prev_x,prev_y, tmp;
    uint tmp2;

    if ((display = XOpenDisplay(NULL)) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "xpointerswap: fatal: cannot open local X display\n");
        exit(100);
    }

    root = DefaultRootWindow(display);

    XQueryPointer(display, root, &fromroot, &tmpwin, &prev_x, &prev_y, &tmp, &tmp, &tmp2);
    XQueryKeymap(display, prevKeymap);

    while(1)
    {
        XQueryPointer(display, root, &fromroot, &tmpwin, &x, &y, &tmp, &tmp, &tmp2);
        if(x!=prev_x || y!=prev_y || hasTyped(display))
        {
            prev_x = x;
            prev_y = y;
            cout<< "(" << x << "," <<  y << ")\n";
        }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

([reference](https://www.linuxforums.org/forum/programming-scripting/59649-how-capture-x11-events-globally.html))

It listens to keyboard messages, but when a key is pressed, it types the location of mouse pointer (I want it to print keycode instead). How can I change it so that it prints the keycode instead (when a key is pressed)?

Comment: This code does things that make no sense whatsoever, but if you must use it, bit N in the keymap array corresponds to keycode N. Bits that are on are keys that are down. Bit `N` in the array is bit `N % 8` in `keymap[N / 8]` and you can check it with `(1 << (N % 8)) & keymap[N / 8]`.

Comment: what is superfluous in this code. Is there a simpler representaion for printing the key?

Comment: This code is doing queries to an X server in a tight loop. If I found out someone does this to my machine I would kick him out presto. X is event-driven. Wait for events. Google for "x11 keylogger" if you want to see how it's done. This code also queries mouse coordinates for some reason that is beyond my understanding.

Comment: @n.m. http://hamsterbaum.de/index.php/2011/12/10/linux-keylogger-without-root-access/comments/ does the same